# Excel copy cell value from above only if the current cell is blank

Tags: excel

I am wanting to the value of the above cell to the curernt cell below it, ONLY if current cell is empty.  I need this to be dynamic for all cells in a column.

So my Excel file looks like this:

```
1 | Person
2 |
3 | Record
4 | 
5 | Tiger
6 | 
7 | 
8 | Scott
9 |
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
1 | Person
2 | Person
3 | Record
4 | Record
5 | Tiger
6 | Tiger
7 | Tiger
8 | Scott
9 | Scott
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
=IF( ISBLANK(CELL("contents")),INDIRECT("A" & ROW() - 1),"")
```

I'll get either a Circular Reference Warning or just the value 0.  This is for Excel 2010

Comment: More links [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533462/excel-vba-find-and-fill-in-values) Do let me know if they do not answer your queries. See specially @pnuts answer (Non VBA Way) in the duplicate link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to generate the filled in data in a new column.  In `B1` simply use

```
=A1
```

Then, starting in `B2`, use

```
=IF(ISBLANK($A2), $B1, $A2)
```

Copy this formula down to the end of your data.

Comment: Ah okay I didn't think about having to copy into a new column.  That worked.  Now my question is how do I make the values in the cells generated from the formula persistent/static so it doesn't show the formula anymore?   ** Ah nvm right click -> paste special -> values