# EXCEL VBA Search for values between 2 numbers and Store search results in an array?

Tags: vba, excel

[EXCEL VBA Store search results in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312226/excel-vba-store-search-results-in-an-array)

The above link is similar to what I am after, however, I wanted to know if it's possible to search for say cells with numbers between 0.5 and 1.5?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can loop through the cells and check if the value is between 0.5 and 1.5 and then store the value in an array

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. And I think the code in the link you provided will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Sivaprasath, I might try that. L42, I am having trouble with the exact syntax for the search field. How would I be able to go about this? E.g. SearchString =  >0.5 & <1.5??? Thanks for your quick responses guys :)